# Consume WCF Restful service with datacontract

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, datacontract

I have created the following restfull web service:

**Interface**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISIGService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
                   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
                   UriTemplate = "GetTicket/")]
    Ticket GetTicket(string user, string pwd);
}
```

**Implementation**

```
public class SIGService : ISIGService
{
    public Ticket GetTicket(string user, string pwd)
    {
        return new Ticket()
        {
            Usuario = "xx",
            UsuarioNombre = "xxx",
            UsuarioId = "xxx"
        };
    }
```

**Contract**

```
[DataContract]
public class Ticket
{
    [DataMember]
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string UsuarioNombre { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Usuario { get; set; }
}
```

I need to **consume this service**, from a web application, and get the typed object `Ticket`, I have included a service reference for this.

**Server side code**:

```
string urlService = 
    String.Format("http://localhost:22343/SIGService.svc/GetTicket/?user='{0}'&pwd='{1}'", 
                 usuario, password);

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlService);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

I put a `text` variable just to get something, sort of lost here.

I don't seem to get this object, could you give some pointers on this?

Comment: What does your server-side **config** look like??

Comment: @marc_s here you go, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, you just need to change your URL from

```
http://localhost:22343/SIGService.svc/GetTicket/?user='{0}'&pwd='{1}'
```

to using the proper **REST** syntax (since you're using a REST service):

```
http://localhost:22343/SIGService.svc/GetTicket/{user}/{pwd}
```

Sample:

```
http://localhost:22343/SIGService.svc/GetTicket/daniel/topsecret
```

No `?` or `user=` or single quotes necessary ....

With this, the value from `{0}` will be passed into the `user` parameter, and the value from `{1}` to the `pwd` parameter.

For consuming the service, I would recommend you check out the excellent [**RestSharp**](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp) library which makes using your REST service a breeze.

Your code would look something like this:

```
// set up the REST Client
string baseServiceUrl = "http://localhost:22343/SIGService.svc";

RestClient client = new RestClient(baseServiceUrl);

// define the request
RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
request.Method = Method.GET;
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
request.Resource = "GetTicket/{user}/{pwd}";
request.AddParameter("user", "daniel", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
request.AddParameter("pwd", "top$ecret", ParameterType.UrlSegment);

// make the call and have it deserialize the XML result into a Ticket object
var result = client.Execute<Ticket>(request);

if (result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Ticket ticket = result.Data;
}
```

Comment: Excellent response, but do you have an alternate response without this Rest library? Thanks

Comment: @DanielV: well, you can use the `WebRequest` as you did - but then you get back a string of XML and you have to deal with deserializing it into an object yourself - too much work....

Comment: the code works perfectly, too much work to serialize the xml indeed.